# FAB Button Gives Error When Use With Bottom Navigation View

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottom navigation view and at the center of bottom navigation view I have a floating action button. I start fragments when click on bottom navigation view items and when click on float action button I start an activity. Fragments are loading correctly but when I click on fab button sometimes it run correctly but sometimes it gives error.

I think, it gives error because I try to load fragment in activity and then I try to open a different activity when a fragment loaded in activity. But I couldn't fix it.

Menu :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5auA.jpg

---

Relative Part of Main Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    private Context context;
    private SharedPreference sharedPreference;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = MainActivity.this;
        sharedPreference = SharedPreference.getInstance(context);

        if (getIntent().hasExtra(Constants.SCREEN_TAG)) {
            String type = getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.SCREEN_TAG);
        }

        FloatingActionButton fabMainActivity = findViewById(R.id.fabMainActivity);

        BottomNavigationView bnvMainActivity = findViewById(R.id.bnvMainActivity);
        bnvMainActivity.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        loadFragment(new DiscoverFragment());

        fabMainActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostJobActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener onNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.navigation_discover:
                    selectedFragment = new DiscoverFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_nearby:
                    selectedFragment = new NearbyFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.empty_menu:
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_notification:
                    selectedFragment = new NotificationFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_profile:
                    selectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                    break;
            }
            loadFragment(selectedFragment);
            return true;
        }
    };

    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.flMainActivity, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

---

Main Activity XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity.MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/app_background">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlTopBackgroundMainActivity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/top_background"
            android:layout_gravity="top">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivLogoWithTextMainActivity"
                android:layout_width="142dp"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="247dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="247dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/terms_activity_logo_with_text"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_with_text" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivMessagesMainActivity"
                android:layout_width="33dp"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:src="@drawable/message_icon"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/messages_icon" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flMainActivity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rlTopBackgroundMainActivity" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bnvMainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_menu_color"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bapMainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_menu_color"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:fabCradleMargin="7dp"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabMainActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_2"
        app:tint="@android:color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/post_job_icon"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bapMainActivity"
        app:maxImageSize="35dp" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---

Relative Part of Post Job Activity : (Post Job Activity also in frame layout.)

```
public class PostJobActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_job);
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
           context = PostJobActivity.this;
        
           btnBackToMainActivityPostJobActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(PostJobActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
   
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(PostJobActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    
}
```

---

Error Message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction.doAddOp(FragmentTransaction.java:161)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:179)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction.replace(FragmentTransaction.java:225)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction.replace(FragmentTransaction.java:200)
        at dk.lejekspert.lejekspertrekrutter.Activity.MainActivity.loadFragment(MainActivity.java:133)
        at dk.lejekspert.lejekspertrekrutter.Activity.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:58)
        at dk.lejekspert.lejekspertrekrutter.Activity.MainActivity$3.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:126)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(BottomNavigationView.java:243)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView$1.onClick(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:124)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5723)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22689)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6364)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

---

Any idea to solve this problem?
Thanks.

---

Edit : I added a sentence to my bottom_navigation_menu.xml file to make not enable menu item below fab button.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/empty_menu"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:title="@string/nearby" />
```

Also this code part is not necessary anymore.

```
case R.id.empty_menu:
     break;
```

Comment: what if `switch (menuItem.getItemId())`doesn't match any case? Have you used a debugger?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Check the  `case R.id.empty_menu:`. In this case `loadFragment(null);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue happens when you call `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.flMainActivity, fragment);` with `fragment` = `null`.

Check the `onNavigationItemSelected`.

```
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
            //...
            case R.id.empty_menu:
                break;   //  <-- this case
        }
        loadFragment(selectedFragment);
        return true;
```

In this case the `selectedFragment` is `null`.
Checking the screen in the question it seems that you are using in the `BottomNavigationView` a menuItem without icon exactly behind the FAB.

Comment: Thanks for solution. It is true. I couldn't see that before you said. I tried to alternative solutions. But finally I didn't change anything. I added to menu item xml android:enabled="false" sentence. Now it works.                                                                <item
        android:id="@+id/empty_menu"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:title="@string/nearby" />